# How to prevent "scroll to top button" from going over the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

What's the simplest way to force the scroll to top button from going into the footer? I want it to stay above the footer at all times since I plan to add links and text in there that it will eventually cover. It should stop right before hitting the footer and not go down any lower.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9s3kRT5tFBBHFVc8eT/9rwn1qub/5/

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
footer {
  margin: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible 
  <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong>.</div>

<footer>
  This is a footer
</footer>

<script>
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _stay above the footer at all times_ <- in this case you can just modify `bottom` to be heigher.

Comment: That would make it higher even when the footer is not in view and would look weird. Currently it is on the bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }

  // check that button is not lower than footer.
  let footerElement = document.getElementById('footer');
  let footerElementRect = footerElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  let mybuttonPositionBottom = mybutton.offsetTop + mybutton.offsetHeight;
  if (footerElementRect.y < mybuttonPositionBottom) {
    // if button is lower than footer.
    // modify css bottom.
    let diffheight = mybuttonPositionBottom - footerElementRect.y;
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(mybutton);
    let addBottom = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('bottom')) + diffheight;
    mybutton.style.bottom = addBottom + 'px'; // maybe add more 10 px for bottom space of a button.
  } else {
    // if button is heigher than footer. this including scroll up.
    // remove custom css bottom.
    mybutton.style.bottom = '';
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

  <div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible
    <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong>.</div>
  <div id="footer">
    This is footer.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[See it in action on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xgrfysc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Get the button
const mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const footer = document.getElementById('footer');
const btnMarginBottom = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(mybutton).getPropertyValue('bottom'));

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  const footStartPos = footer.getBoundingClientRect().y;

    if (window.innerHeight > footStartPos) {
      mybutton.style.bottom = `${(window.innerHeight - footStartPos) + btnMarginBottom}px`;
    } else {
      mybutton.style.bottom = '';
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
footer {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible 
  <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong>.</div>

<footer id="footer">
  This is a footer
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```